# How do I check if specific users are logged on with unix?

Tags: unix, grep, putty

I try this

```
#!/bin/sh

until who | grep -E "$*"
do
        sleep 60
done

echo "$* logged in"
```

but it works only with one user written in arguments. I need this shell program to work with multiple users that are written as arguments.

Comment: Do you want to sleep until _all_ specified users are logged in concurrently, or until _any_ of the specified users are logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `$@` and check the output of `who` for every given name:

```
#!/bin/bash
who="$(who)";                                 # Save the output of who
for user in "$@"; do                          # Iterate over $@
    if echo "$who" | grep -q "$user"; then    # Check if $user is in $who
        echo "$user logged in";
    fi;
done;
```

What were you trying to achieve with that loop? Do you want the script to **wait** until a user logs in?

Comment: yes i need to check if any user of argument list is logged on every minute. If one of them logged on i need to show information about him and end loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` needs some work, because it does not limit the match to the first word on each line.  Alternatively, filter the result from `who`.  Here is a revised script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DONE=no
while [ $DONE = no ]
do
    who="$(who | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' |sort -u)"
    for user in "$@"
    do
        for WHO in $who
        do
            if [ $WHO = $user ]
            then
                echo "$user logged in"
                DONE=yes
                break              
            fi
        done
    done
    [ $DONE = no ] && sleep 60
done
```

As you can see, the `grep` is unnecessary.

Finally, change it to plain `/bin/sh`, because there is no need for a specific shell in this example.

Comment: Good point about tightening the loose `grep` match.  That's a very common shell error that's never a problem until one day you're looking for user `moo` and user `jmoody` is logged in.   I'd +1 you again for the underused `sort -u` if I could.